# Как закрепить значок на одном месте?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как закрепить значок на яндекс карте на одном месте? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Создайте свою карту в [конструкторе карт Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor). Объект, который вы там создадите, будет привязан к карте.